# google maps licensing for use with ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, licensing

I've developed an iPhone application that sends off emails which contain google maps, embedded using the Google Static Maps API.  The app will be for sale on the iTunes store (ie not free).

Do I need to get a Google Maps Business account? If so, how do I even apply for an account?

A point in the right direction would be appreciated.  I contacted google but got the default reply that created more questions that it answered.  eg it said:

"Note: 
a) The sale of a product with Google Maps integration requires a special approval and associated licence upgrade."

but it didn't say how to do any of this.

Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try their [contact form for business account inquiries](http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/request.py?&contact_type=gme#utm_campaign=en&utm_medium=et&utm_source=devsite-en-compare)?

Comment: yep - that's the one that triggers the default reply.

Comment: Did you see the latest answer? Is he correct?

Comment: This is about Google Maps API in e.g. in a Webwiew, you sure can use Apple Maps/Mapkit for free.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing / terms of use / legal issues, not programming or software development. See the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Google:

---

**Usage Limits**

The Google Places API has the following query limits:

1. Users with an API key are allowed 1 000 requests per 24 hour period.
2. Users who have verified their identity through the APIs console are allowed 100 000 requests per 24 hour period. A credit card is required for verification, by enabling billing in the console. We ask for your credit card purely to validate your identity. Your card will not be charged for use of the Places API.

   ---

So all you need is to give your Credit Card information and pay nothing.

Comment: I see.  Looks like static maps api is free for 25k requests per day, so that should be plenty. Thanks very much.

Comment: We developers share :) no need to thank

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to use the free Google Maps API on the iPhone if the App is for Sale unless you use Android with Google's store. See 9.1.2 Exceptions: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

> (Free Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile application that is sold for a fee through an online store and is downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store.

A commercial Maps Api License is too expensive for most cases.
Note: This mostly affects Webviews, because the built in Mapkit on newer iOS serves Apple Maps, not Google Maps.